# Regex find last 4 digits and 1 special character

Tags: c#, regex

How do I find the last 4 digits and 1 @ using regx?

@ character will never be the last character.

123@1234@1234**567@1**  ---> returns 567@1

123@1234@1234**56@12**  ---> returns 56@12

123@1234@1234**5@123**   ---> returns 5@123

123@1234@1234@**1234**   ---> returns 1234

Thanks for the comments bringing up these variations

Update:

123@123**4@23@1**  —> returns 4@23@1

12@123@1**2@1@1@1**  —> returns 2@1@1@1

Comment: Unless you have more variations, shouldn't this do? https://dotnetfiddle.net/CGjqBt - For instance, what if the input is `123@1234@23@1`?

Comment: Is this valid? "@12345" -> "2345" ?

Comment: What about `1@2@3@4@5@6` or `123@@@456`?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen For your variant I would like to return 4@23@1. Would it be something like [\d{1,4}@*] ?

Comment: @Toto both of them will return 3456.

Comment: @Rand Random yes 2345

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/WV8RBu/1/) what you want?

Comment: @Toto - looks good, the only things I found that could be questionable are what if the string doesn't contain a `@` at all? eg. "1234" is it valid? or if a string ends with `@`? OP stated that wont be the case but maybe the regex should cover the case?

Comment: @Toto yes this is exactly what I want!!!

Comment: @Rand Random good point. But in my case the string will always has @ and @ won’t be the last character

Comment: @RandRandom: The regex also matches `1234` and `1234@`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex seems working with your test cases:

```
(\d{4}|(?:\d@*){4})$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/WV8RBu/1/)

Comment: I made some changes on the regex to meet my requirement though : (\d{3}|(?:\d@*){3})[^@]$

Answer (score -1):

You can simply loop througt the string starting from the end, and count the digit. Once you reach the number of digit wanted, substring from its index.

```
private static string LastNDigit(string input, int nbDigit)
{
    var digitCount = 0;
    var sIndex = 0;           

    for (int i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(input[i])) digitCount++;
        if (digitCount == nbDigit) {
            sIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return input.Substring(sIndex);
}
```

Usage:

```
var inputs = new[]{
        "123@1234@1234567@1",
        "123@1234@123456@12",
        "123@1234@12345@123",
        "123@1234@1234@1234"
};

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input + " => " + LastNDigit(input, 4));
}
```

[live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qe5ng5)

Comment: OP has asked for a regular expression

Comment: @MarkCooper, I do believe that my answer is wrong. But using Linq instead of regex has nothing to do with it. I have ignored the "1 special character". And didn't check  the expected output. There is a ton of regex question where the best or accepted answer is "use a simple for loop". X/Y problem by definition always have a answers that is not within the range of the question.

Comment: Here is an update code that satisfy the requirement. Still not using regex.